# Error where "__str__ returned non-string", but shows output

Tags: python, string

In my class I have

```
def __str__(self):
     print "abc"
```

When I create an object `a` of this class, and type `print a`, it prints `abc` (correctly), but then also gives the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    print a
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between *printing* a value and *returning* it. Printing the value displays it in the console for the user to see, whereas returning means it's available to other code that's calling that function. Your `__str__` method should be:

```
def __str__(self):
     return "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

`__str__` is supposed to return a string

```
def __str__(self):
     return "abc"
```

Quoting from the [`__str__` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__),

> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to
>   compute the “informal” string representation of an object. This
>   differs from **repr**() in that it does not have to be a valid Python
>   expression: a more convenient or concise representation may be used
>   instead. **The return value must be a string object.**